# NGINX setup for REST API returning default configuration

Tags: nginx

I've hired a VPS to play with some personal projects. To get started, I'm trying to set it up to host a REST API using Node.js, as I've only ever used Spring Boot for that.

I've implemented the solutions by adapting from the following guides:

https://www.robinwieruch.de/node-express-server-rest-api (most of the API code looks like this)

https://itnext.io/building-restful-api-with-node-js-express-js-and-postgresql-the-right-way-b2e718ad1c66 (but I'm slowly converting to use the standards from here)

For the actual deployment, I've changed to bundle the API with Babel and I'm deploying it with PM2.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-plus-as-an-api-gateway-part-1/ (not Plus though)

(All those links are available via http://web.archive.org/ so they aren't going anywhere anytime soon)

I created another Node.js project using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=axios) to test the REST requests. Running it in the same VPS works, but I had to change the API code to bind to `localhost`. Before, with the binding address unspecified, it was binding to an IPv6 `localhost` (if I understood correctly) and, since my domain doesn't work with IPv6, I'll stick with IPv4.

On the NGINX side I've made the most changes as I only have 1 API now and I won't be using load balancing. Also, I've changed the naming policy. I'll be using `example.com/app_or_project_name/api_or_web_or_other_kind_of_interface/project_specific_routes`.

Here's how my NGINX setup is looking like. I've anonymized it and changed to use the same name as the NGINX example:

> api_backends.conf

```
upstream warehouse {
    zone api 64k;
    server 127.0.0.1:some_port_number;
}
```

That's the REST API host and port number.

> api_conf.d/warehouse_api.conf

```
# Warehouse API
#
location /warehouse/api/ {
    # Policy configuration here (authentication, rate limiting, logging, more...)
    #
    access_log /var/log/nginx/warehouse_api.log main;
    auth_request /_validate_apikey;

    # URI routing
    #
    proxy_pass http://warehouse;

    return 404; # Catch-all
}
```

> api_gateway.conf

```
include api_backends.conf;
include api_keys.conf;

server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api_access.log main; # Each API may also log to a separate file

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my-domain.net;

    # TLS config
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    # API definitions, one per file
    include api_conf.d/*.conf;

    # Error responses
    # error_page 404 = @400;         # Invalid paths are treated as bad requests
    proxy_intercept_errors on;     # Do not send backend errors to the client
    include api_json_errors.conf;  # API client friendly JSON error responses
    default_type application/json; # If no content-type then assume JSON

    # API key validation
    location = /_validate_apikey {
        internal;

        if ($http_apikey = "") {
            return 401; # Unauthorized
        }
        if ($api_client_name = "") {
            return 403; # Forbidden
        }

        return 204; # OK (no content)
    }

}
```

I might set `proxy_intercept_errors` to `off` once it's working. I'll have to make some tests to see what changes in the responses.

> api_json_errors.conf

Same as example.

> default.conf

```
server {
    server_name  www.my-domain.net;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.my-domain.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = my-domain.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen       80;
    server_name  my-domain.net www.my-domain.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I had to make some changes here because there was a combination of address and port that had a duplicate `server` configuration.

> nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/api_gateway.conf; # All API gateway configuration
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;    # Regular web traffic
}
```

When I run the same test project outside the VPS, I get the following result:

```json
{
  message: 'Request failed with status code 404',
  name: 'Error',
  description: undefined,
  number: undefined,
  fileName: undefined,
  lineNumber: undefined,
  columnNumber: undefined,
  stack: '...',
  config: {
    url: 'https://my-domain.net/warehouse/api/messages',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    apikey: '...',
    data: undefined
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

One thing I managed to figure out is that the 404 error is returned by `warehouse_api.conf` because, if I change `return 404;` to another code, that's the code I'll get.

I've enabled debugging in NGINX but I couldn't understand the output, even after searching a little:

```
2021/07/22 11:54:17 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *757 using location: @404 "/warehouse/api/messages?"
2021/07/22 11:54:31 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *758 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2021/07/22 11:54:31 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *758 rewrite phase: 3
2021/07/22 11:54:31 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *758 http finalize request: 404, "/warehouse/api/messages?" a:1, c:1
2021/07/22 11:54:31 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *758 http special response: 404, "/warehouse/api/messages?"
2021/07/22 11:54:31 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *758 test location: "@400"
2021/07/22 11:54:31 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *758 test location: "@401"
2021/07/22 11:54:31 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *758 test location: "@403"
2021/07/22 11:54:31 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *758 test location: "@404"
2021/07/22 11:54:31 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *758 using location: @404 "/warehouse/api/messages?"
```

I tried a few different approaches to search about all this but couldn't find any leads.

So, what's going on, what's wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

## Update 2021-08-04

Following @jose-fernando-lopez-fernandez 's answer, I changed `api_conf.d/warehouse_api.conf` to the following:

```
# Warehouse API
#
location /warehouse/api/ {
    # Policy configuration here (authentication, rate limiting, logging, more...)
    #
    access_log /var/log/nginx/warehouse_api.log main;
    auth_request /_validate_apikey;

    # URI routing
    #
    location /warehouse/api/ {
        proxy_pass http://warehouse;
    }

    return 404; # Catch-all
}
```

to keep it in line with the examples I'm following. I tested again and got an 401 error instead. I checked and I was passing the `apikey` incorrectly.

I fixed it, tested again and got a 404 again. But now I'm getting a lot more output out of `nginx-debug`.

I've anonymized it. I've replaced `apikey` by another I generated and won't be using for anything.

I've also replaced `posix_memalign`, `http cleanup add`, `free`, `chain writer in` and `malloc` by strings of the same length with random bytes. I don't know if it should be anonymous or not. If it's needed for the solution of this question please ask and I'll add them back in on a need to know basis.

Here goes:

```
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 generic phase: 5
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 generic phase: 6
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 generic phase: 7
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 access phase: 8
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 access phase: 9
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 access phase: 10
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 auth request handler
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http subrequest "/_validate_apikey?"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http posted request: "/_validate_apikey?"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 test location: "/warehouse/api/"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 test location: "/_validate_apikey"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 using configuration "=/_validate_apikey"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script var
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script var: "o6ZlKSX24MCY/uPwCRl80WAS"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script value: ""
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script equal
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script equal: no
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script if
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script if: false
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script var
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http map started
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script var: "o6ZlKSX24MCY/uPwCRl80WAS"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http map: "o6ZlKSX24MCY/uPwCRl80WAS" "client_one"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script var: "client_one"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script value: ""
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script equal
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script equal: no
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script if
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script if: false
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http finalize request: 0, "/_validate_apikey?" a:1, c:2
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 auth request done s:204
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http wake parent request: "/warehouse/api/messages?"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http posted request: "/warehouse/api/messages?"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 access phase: 10
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 auth request handler
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 auth request set variables
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 post access phase: 11
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 generic phase: 12
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 generic phase: 13
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 posix_memalign: 218512C89A2ED401:4096 @16
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http init upstream, client timer: 0
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 epoll add event: fd:3 op:3 ev:80002005
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script copy: "Host"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script var: "warehouse"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script copy: "Connection"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script copy: "close"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script copy: ""
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http script copy: ""
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "apikey: o6ZlKSX24MCY/uPwCRl80WAS"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "User-Agent: axios/0.21.1"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header:
"GET /warehouse/api/messages HTTP/1.0
Host: warehouse
Connection: close
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
apikey: o6ZlKSX24MCY/uPwCRl80WAS
User-Agent: axios/0.21.1

"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http cleanup add: 90C9DA232086B6FA
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 get rr peer, try: 1
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 stream socket 15
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 epoll add connection: fd:15 ev:80002005
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 connect to 127.0.0.1:some_port_number, fd:15 #2
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http upstream connect: -2
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 posix_memalign: A9E50626EC2A1D36:128 @16
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 event timer add: 15: 60000:878601635
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http finalize request: -4, "/warehouse/api/messages?" a:1, c:2
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http request count:2 blk:0
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http run request: "/warehouse/api/messages?"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/warehouse/api/messages"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http upstream request: "/warehouse/api/messages?"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http upstream send request handler
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http upstream send request
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http upstream send request body
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 chain writer buf fl:1 s:225
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 chain writer in: 4C4F626384F523C9
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 writev: 225 of 225
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 event timer del: 15: 878601635
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 event timer add: 15: 60000:878601636
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http upstream request: "/warehouse/api/messages?"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http upstream process header
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 malloc: 1D36E73206B5EE11:4096
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 recv: eof:1, avail:-1
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 recv: fd:15 444 of 4096
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy status 404 "404 Not Found"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "X-Powered-By: Express"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "Content-Length: 168"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "Date: Wed, 04 Aug 2021 17:43:08 GMT"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header: "Connection: close"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http proxy header done
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 finalize http upstream request: 404
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 finalize http proxy request
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 free rr peer 1 0
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 close http upstream connection: 15
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 free: A9E50626EC2A1D36, unused: 48
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 event timer del: 15: 878601636
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 reusable connection: 0
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http finalize request: 404, "/warehouse/api/messages?" a:1, c:1
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 http special response: 404, "/warehouse/api/messages?"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 test location: "@400"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 test location: "@401"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 test location: "@403"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 test location: "@404"
2021/08/04 17:43:08 [debug] nginx_pid#nginx_pid: *1 using location: @404 "/warehouse/api/messages?"
```

It seems weird to me that it seems to be considering `warehouse` as a host name. On the other hand, NGINX does define some addresses with that name so it might be related to that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you just stubbed out the proxy-related machinations to be handled at a later time in your warehouse API file, but that actually won't work, as you found out.

```
# Warehouse API
#
location /warehouse/api/ {
    # Policy configuration here (authentication, rate limiting, logging, more...)
    #
    access_log /var/log/nginx/warehouse_api.log main;
    auth_request /_validate_apikey;

    # URI routing
    #
    proxy_pass http://warehouse;

    return 404; # Catch-all
}
```

Compare that one line in charge of URI routing against the version in the example you linked.

```
# Warehouse API
#
location /api/warehouse/ {
    # Policy configuration here (authentication, rate limiting, logging, more...)
    #
    access_log /var/log/nginx/warehouse_api.log main;
    auth_request /_validate_apikey;

    # URI routing
    #
    location /api/warehouse/inventory {
        proxy_pass http://warehouse_inventory;
    }

    location /api/warehouse/pricing {
        proxy_pass http://warehouse_pricing;
    }

    return 404; # Catch-all
}
```

The reason for why the example works but yours doesn't has to do with the "precedence" ("immediacy" might be a better term) of the `return` directive.

As per the documentation, the `return` directive immediately causes Nginx to stop processing the current request and return right away<sup>[1](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return)</sup>. This means your `proxy_pass` directive isn't even getting the chance to even try to execute.

However, in the example, there are two nested, prefix-based locations within the block, which means that Nginx will opt for the longest match. This is why the example request succeeded; the requested URI, `https://api.example.com/api/warehouse/pricing/item001`, matched the second of the two nested location blocks, and thus the request was proxied as expected.

In conclusion, you need to add a nested location block for the `proxy_pass` directive to execute within, if you want to replicate the example. Otherwise, it looks like you should be able to simply remove the `return` directive and your configured upstream backend will be free to try to do its thing.

Comment: Thanks! However, now it's failing further down the line. I've updated the first post with more information.

Comment: I genuinely don't know if this is the source of the problem, but the Warehouse API is a Plus feature isn't it? I honestly have zero experience with it, so I could be wrong, but a 401 sounds like that could be it, right?

Comment: I don't see how that could be the case. In my understanding, the Warehouse API is just an example, where the "Warehouse" is a hypothetical app that accesses a hypothetical API, and the NGINX example shows how to expose that API.